# Mask numeric input in UITextField with Unit

Tags: objective-c, formatting, uitextfield

I have created an UITextField with UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad:

```
tf = [self makeTextField:self.groesse placeholder:@"erforderlich"];
[tf setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Now, I am trying to mask the entered number, that it will be shown for example like `187 cm` in the UITextField. I have tried it with

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(textField == groesseField_) {
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ cm",string];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But now, I am only able to input one digit instead of three for the example above.

Can someone help me, what I am doing wrong? - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because every time the method is called variable `string` contains only one last character. So, you need to add this character to your textField.

This should work:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(textField == groesseField_) {
        NSString *currentString = textField.text;
        if ([currentString isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ cm",string];
        }
        else
        {
            currentString = [currentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" cm" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ cm", string]];
        }
        textField.text = currentString;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also, to you should write specific code to maintain backspace button. But for real, I would rather add `cm` when user ends editing on `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)sender`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the text from a combination of the current text in the text field and the edit being made to the range, then add your suffix:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if(textField == groesseField_) {
    NSString *completeText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    textField.text = [completeText stringByAppendingString:@" cm",];
    return NO;
}
return YES;

}
```